# Multiple geometry types layer in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wfs-t

I am using **OpenLayers** and **Geoserver** in a web map application in which I'd like to implement editable layers by drawing features on it.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html) to save the created features with **WFS-T** and `OpenLayers.Strategy.Save()`, but since Shapefiles only deal with one geometry type at a time, I can't draw, for example, a polygon AND a line on the same layer.

Note: I can't use different layers for different geometry types, it has to be on a single layer due to a tool I am using: OLE ("OpenLayers Editor").

So my question is : is there any way to store multiple geometry types in a single layer with **Geoserver/PostGIS** ?

Comment: To start with you must create a PostGIS table that accepts all kind of geometries with `create table foo (fid serial NOT NULL,attr text);` and `SELECT AddGeometryColumn('foo', 'geom', 4326, 'GEOMETRY', 2 );` Publish that with GeoServer and you may be able to save points, lines, and polygons with WFS-T.